# Error in .(id, SalePrice) : could not find function "."

Tags: r

This is my code and

```r
fwrite(train_data,'./project/volume/data/interim/trainn.csv')
fwrite(test_data[,.(id,SalePrice)],'./project/volume/data/interim/ex_solution.csv')
```

when I run the code it shows that

```
Error in .(id, SalePrice) : could not find function "."
```

Comment: Is test_data a data.table? You can test it using is.data.table.

Comment: Agree with Hutch3232, verify with that or `class(test_data)` or `inherits(test_data, "data.table")`, all should indicate whether you are or are not using a `data.table`. Note that a it is a special "dialect" of `data.frame` (it will inherit that class as well), but that doesn't mean its special methods will work. If needed, use `setDT(tset_data)` (by itself) to convert a `data.frame` or `tbl_df` to `data.table`.

Comment: i tried using is.data.table and it appears to be false, how should I make it to data.table? @Hutch3232

Comment: @Sandy Wang - @r2evans gave a good suggestion to convert it by running `setDT(test_data)`. This happens by-reference (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html), so no need to assign it to anything.